# Eclipse auto-fill class is moving code

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes when I let eclipse auto-generate inherited constructors for me it moves some of my code, like this:

```
public class Music extends Sound{

}
```

becomes:

```
public class Music
    public Music() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    } extends Sound{
}
```

it has happened with ecipse indigo on windows 7 and ubuntu and now it happened on osx lion with juno.

does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: This is an odd one, for sure. Are you sure you havent meddled with Eclipse properties?

Comment: Not happening for me (indigo as well).

Comment: I haven't meddled with any properties, intentionally atleast